# Extra slash in GET request with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make GET request. Url is configured without slash at the end of URL. Server receives url with "/" at the end so I get error 404. I can see response.url with slash, but urlRequest contains URL without it.

Can't understand, what's going on.

```
Meant to send:
http://someUrl.com/api

Sent:
http://someUrl.com/api/
```

Code sample

```
      guard let url = URL(string: self.rootUrl + "/api") else {
        print ("Can't make URL")
      return
    }
   var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
    let sessionConf = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession.init(configuration: sessionConf)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        // check for any errors
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling GET on /api")
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        // make sure we got data
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }
        // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
        do {
            print (urlRequest)
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData) as? [String: Any]
            if ( json == nil ) {
                print ("error json")
                print(response!)
            } else { ....
```

Comment: What you mean by sent , its request you print request or what ?

Comment: You need to look at your server configuration; it seems that /api is a directory and not a "document" (or endpoint)

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish request i print is `http://someUrl.com/api`, response.url i print is `http://someUrl.com/api/`

Comment: may be this from server

Comment: @Paulw11 server? Error is Swift send request adds trailing slash in end. Why it does?

Comment: @Paulw11 @Abdelahad Darwish I use the link `http://someUrl.com/api` on postman and windows client. Its all works

Comment: You are sending a GET request without the / and getting a response that contains the /.  This indicates that the server re-wrote the request.

Comment: @dikkini share postman photo just hide base url only , and what is response on postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift cached response for this request, set `CachePolicy` to ignore reload and try to do `GET` request to other URL and than try again.